# Why SonarQube exclusions are not applied to additional extensions specified in sonar.javascript.file.suffixes?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarscanner

In my sonar-project.properties file I have the following settings:

```
...
sonar.sources=src
sonar.exclusions=src/**/*.test.js
sonar.javascript.file.suffixes=js,jsx
```

However my build is failing with the following error:

```
ERROR: Caused by: Line 346 of report refers to a file which is not configured as a test file: /tmp/app/src/components/__tests__/filters.test.jsx
```

My jenkins logs report accurately that  `58 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns`, verified by using `find . -name "*.test.js" | wc -l = 58`

the same command with jsx gives me 10 results `find . -name "*.test.jsx" | wc -l` meaning the `sonar.javascript.file.suffixes=js,jsx` is not applied to the exclusions property.

How do I exclude files in my source with both .js and .jsx extensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did it partially correct. To exclude files you have to set `sonar.exclusions`. You did it, but only for `js` files, so the answer to your problem is:

```
...
sonar.sources=src
sonar.exclusions=src/**/*.test.js,src/**/*.test.jsx
sonar.javascript.file.suffixes=js,jsx
```

`sonar.javascript.file.suffixes` informs JavaScript analyzer which files contain JavaScript code. It does not influence `sonar.exclusions`, so you have to define all patterns by yourself.